# When calculating an effect for a general spell, do I use the base level or the total level?

Tags: ars-magica-5

The book itself isn't terribly specific about this, and I can't seem to find any examples of a general spell with a specific level for reference.  Do I only use the base of the spell when calculating effect, or do I add in modifiers like targets, duration, range, and requisites when calculating effect?  More specifically, if I were to learn the Perdo Vim spell Demon's Eternal Oblivion at level 20, would it reduce a demon's Might by 20 or 30 points?

> Reduce a target's Might Score by the level of the spell + 10, as long as the spell penetrates the creature's resistance.

This is the general effect listed, for reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You use the base level, but be careful of the low leveled versions of the spell that depart from the 1mag/5level paradigm.**

So, let's look at the case of DEO. (Core Book, p160, first printing)

> DEMON’S ETERNAL OBLIVION
>
> R: Voice, D: Mom, T: Ind
>
> Weakens and possibly destroys a demon.
> If the spell penetrates the demon’s Magic
> Resistance, the demon loses Might Score equal
> to the spell’s level.
> (Base effect, +2 Voice)

This is very telling. (We'll get to low levels in a second, cause they're annoying.)

If I have DEO at 20, the demon loses 20 might (assuming I can penetrate its magic resistance.) This is because the +2 mags from voice are neatly countered by the "+10 levels" of the spell's bonus.

If, on the other hand, I have DEO at 10, this implies a base 4, +2 magnitudes voice). Base 4 translates into 14 points of might destroyed. Yes, this is headache inducing.

Comment: I think we always played it as "+2 magnitudes" rather than "+10 levels", keeping it simple. DEO at lv10 takes down 10 Might, c'est tout. I feel this keeps to the spirit of the rule while avoiding the anomalies you point out at low levels.

Comment: That certainly makes much more sense, and reviewing the guidelines of the *other* bloody spells in the section, it's quite quite reasonable. It is, however, a house rule.

Comment: Aha!  So I can go Base Level 3, Voice +2, and get a level 5 spell that destroys 13 levels of demon might.  I was under the impression it was base level, but thought it might possibly be total level, so that long range/high duration/multiple target spells had a decent minimum.  Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: While that is... unfortunately true, I do urge you to discuss with your troupe the alternate house rule that @lisardggY suggested above. Also be advised that actually poking demons in any way just gets you into more trouble. (If they're played correctly.)